# I am getting errors while copying files from local to hdfs

Tags: hadoop

I am getting error while copying files from local file system to hdfs, 
will you please help me regarding this, 
I am using this command :

```
hadoopd fs -put text.txt file
```

Comment: Can you please specify the error you are getting

Answer (score 2):

`put` and `copyFromLocal` command helps you to copy data from your local system to HDFS,provided you have the permission to do so.

```
hadoop fs -put /path/to/textfile /path/to/hdfs
OR
hadoop dfs -put /path/to/textfile /path/to/hdfs
```

Comming to your error:

You typed the above command as

```
hadoopd fs
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
hadoop dfs -put /text.txt /file
```

`hadoop dfs -put /path/to/local/file /path/to/hdfs/file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command

`hadoop fs -copyFromLocal text.txt <path_to_hdfs_directory_where_you_want_to_keep_text.txt>`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specific error you are getting, it's difficult to answer.  The other responders posted the proper syntax.  However, it is not uncommon to see permission issues when attempting to copy files to HDFS.

By default the user and group are typically "hdfs" and "supergroup".  Your user account likely doesn't belong to "supergroup" and will get permission denied errors.  Try running the command as:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -put /path/to/local/file /path/to/hdfs/file
```

or

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop dfs -put /path/to/local/file /path/to/hdfs/file
```

You can get around having to do this by changing the ownership and permission of the destination directory on HDFS to be more permissive.

Answer (score 0):

"DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/hduser/myfile could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock". From this I thinrk your data node is not running/properly. Check that in cluster UI.Then try

hadoop dfs -put /path/file /hdfs/file (hadoop YARN)
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /path/file /hdfs/file (hadoop1.x)